# TextView stretches CardView when text overflows instead of a new line

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 MaterialCardViews that I'd like to share the same width on a screen and have achieved this using a GridLayout with 2 columns, but I'm struggling to keep the width constraint when the text inside the MaterialCardViews starts being longer than the desired width.

Desired: 
https://imgur.com/a/BB9H4zZ

Current Problem:
https://imgur.com/a/gyXJxZc

Here's my current implementation of the Cards:

```
<GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/search_results_grid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="2"
                android:useDefaultMargins="true">

                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#eaeaea"
                        android:lines="1"
                        android:text="String"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:autoSizeTextType="uniform">
                    </TextView>
                </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


                <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="String"
                        android:background="#eaeaea">
                    </TextView>
              </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


            </GridLayout>
```

From other stackoverflow posts, I've tried to add `android:inputType="textMultiline"`, disable horizontal scrolling, and `android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"` but no changes resulted.

Comment: I recommend using Constraint layout instead of Grid. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/search_results_grid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/leftCardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/rightCardView">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#eaeaea"
                android:lines="1"
                android:text="StringLongLongStringStringStringStringString"/>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/rightCardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/leftCardView"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#eaeaea"
                android:text="String"/>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: My goal in creating this view is to create multiple cards dynamically based off the number of search results I get from my API. Would I have to create multiple constraint layouts to achieve this?

Comment: @TinLa Okay. If that's the case, are you using RecyclerView. Is each card used for one search result ? Do you want each row to have two search results ?

Comment: @TinLa Just saw your above comment. You will have to use Recycler View with GridLayoutManager. Check example here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/simple-android-grid-example-using-recyclerview-with-gridlayoutmanager

Answer (score 0):

Use `LinearLayout` instead of `GridLayout` to show your `CardViews`, and give equal weight to both the `CardViews` like below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/search_results_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:background="#eaeaea"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="StringLongLongStringStringStringStringString"/>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            android:background="#eaeaea"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="StringLongLongString"/>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

If you remove the `android:lines` tag from `TextView`, next stuff will go on the next line and not forward like it happens right now.

Comment: Thanks for this! Is it possible to have the extra characters to be instead cut off, be put in the next line? Also, I'd like to list an undefined amount cards in a similar format which would result in multiple rows of cards with 2 cards per row. Would I have to create a new linear layout for every row?

Comment: They go into next line. I told you in the last part itself. If you remove the lines tag, they'll go to next line